# Find all scores for the 2nd to most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a history table that contains a score per group per date (PK is group, date). What is the SQL query that can retrieve the scores for all groups for the 2nd most recent date?

ETA: The dates are the same across groups (each score is entered into the history table at the same time for each group).

Comment: has any of these answers helped at all or are they missing the mark?

Comment: any response would be great hope you can clarify why you are not commenting problems with any of the answers not fixing your issue and or not selecting an answer at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *
from ScoreHistory sc1
where exists
(
    select GroupId, max(ScoreDate) RecentScoreDate
    from ScoreHistory sc2
    where not exists
    (
        select GroupId, max(ScoreDate) RecentScoreDate
        from ScoreHistory sc3
        group by GroupId
        having GroupId = sc2.GroupId and max(ScoreDate) = sc2.ScoreDate
    )
    group by GroupId
    having GroupId = sc1.GroupId and max(ScoreDate) = sc1.ScoreDate
)
```

Setup:

```
create table ScoreHistory(GroupId int, ScoreDate datetime)

insert ScoreHistory
    select 1, '2011-06-14' union all
    select 1, '2011-06-15' union all
    select 1, '2011-06-16' union all
    select 2, '2011-06-15' union all
    select 2, '2011-06-16' union all
    select 2, '2011-06-17'
```

The query would looks as simple as below for MS SQL 2005 +

```
;with cte
as
(
    select *, row_number() over(partition by GroupId order by ScoreDate desc) RowNumber
    from ScoreHistory
)
select *
from cte
where RowNumber = 2
```

Comment: Yeah this query does not return the scores that he is requesting in his question or is it retrieving all the groups within that date it will most likely only get the first occurrance of the 2nd most recent date.. So YAY for upvotes without understanding code output...

Comment: @Laurence Burke - First of all it is not fair to expect the precise answer without showing table structure, input and desired output in the question. Secondly regarding to my answer, if there is a separate `Score` field, it can be added to the group - updated the answer.

Comment: For the 2005+ version, by sorting on group also `order by [date], [group] desc` the query plan seems to be able to use the index.

Answer (score 3):

You need two aggregates

1. get max dates per group
2. get max dates per group that are less then the dates from step 1
3. join back to the score from this aggregate

Something like

```
SELECT
    Group, Date, Score
FROM
    ( ..2nd max date per group
    SELECT
       Group, MAX(Date) AS TakeMe
    FROM
        ( --max date per group
        SELECT
           Group, MAX(Date) AS IgnoreMe
        FROM
           MyTable
        GROUP BY
           Group
        ) ex
        JOIN
        MyTable M ON ex.Group = M.Group AND ex.IgnoreMe > M.Date
    GROUP BY
        M.Group
    ) inc
    JOIN
    MyTable M2 ON inc.Group = M2.Group AND inc.TakeMe = M2.Date
```

This is *so* much easier on SQL Server 2005 with ROW_NUMBER()...

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I am trying to get the `TOP 2 DISTINCT` Dates Desc first which will work if you are using just dates and not datetimes. Then reversing that table and getting the `TOP 1`  and using that result as the 2nd most recent date to get the groups scores.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT TOP 1 x.[date]
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 2 DISTINCT [date]
    FROM YourTable
    ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS x
ORDER BY [date] ASC) AS y
ON y.[date] = YourTable.[date]
```

I think this may need a `WHERE y.date = YourTable.date` but I am not sure

Comment: Actually, OP has clarified that dates are the same for all groups. Comments and -1 removed. So this query works *now* we know this... you didn't when you posted...

Comment: The DISTINCT is out of order. Should be SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 [date]

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM tblScore
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL
    FROM tblScore as tblOuter
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM tblScore As tblInner
        WHERE tblInner.[group] = tblOuter.[group]
        GROUP BY [group]
        HAVING MAX(tblInner.[date]) = tblOuter.[date]
    ) 
    AND tblOuter.[group] = tblScore.[group]
    GROUP BY [group]
    HAVING MAX(tblOuter.[date]) = tblScore.[date]
)
```